# catch exception while connecting android application to mysql using jdbc

Tags: java, android

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button login,signup;
EditText name,pass;
ResultSet res;
int a=0;
```

setting id to the views in xml page

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    login=(Button)findViewById(R.id.login);
    signup=(Button)findViewById(R.id.sign);
    name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    pass=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
```

establishing mysql connection on "login" button click.

```
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            String n=name.getText().toString();
            String p=pass.getText().toString();
            Connection co
            Statement st;
            try
            {
             Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
 co =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost             /mcon","root","");
```

retriving the data from login "table" in mysql.i have stored two fields in login table for username and password with same value "admin".On the login button click the page will directed to admin page if the user enter correct admin, admin in the edit text.

```
st = co.createStatement();
res=st.executeQuery("select * from login");
Boolean rec = res.next();
                if (!rec) 
              {
             Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"norecordinthetable",
      Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(                    );

                } 
                 else {
                    do {
                        String s3 = res.getString(1);
                        String s4 = res.getString(2);

                        if (n.equals(s3) && p.equals(s4)) 
      Intent iii=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Admin.class);
                   startActivity(iii);
                            a = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                    } while (res.next());
                }
                    if (a == 0)
           {
   Toast.makeText(getApplication(),"wrongName/Password",
           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        name.setText("");
                        pass.setText("");
                    }               
                      st.close();
                co.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
Toast.makeText(getApplication(), "error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }       

        }
    });
```

Comment: Android doesn't support mysql  you need to write a webservice

Comment: wow - what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

the jdbc is really a overdue framework,try to use some new ones like mybaits. You will get much more help for the widely using of mybaits.

Answer (score 0):

Make Sure you have mysql-connector-java-3.0.17-ga-bin.jar driver.
Check for permissions in the androidManifest.xml file.